# Why won't my animation run?

Tags: javascript

When I run the code on my site it starts off with image jackhammers1 instead of jackhammers0 and won't execute the startBouncing() method. it just displays the form with one image and no animation. It is an example copied from the textbook so I don't see how it shouldn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

<title>JackHammer</title>


<script type="text/javascript">

/* <![CDATA[ */

var jackhammers = newArray(11);
var curJackhammer = 0;
var direction;
var begin;
jackhammers[0] = "jackhammer0.gif";
jackhammers[1] = "jackhammer1.gif";
jackhammers[2] = "jackhammer2.gif";
jackhammers[3] = "jackhammer3.gif";
jackhammers[4] = "jackhammer4.gif";
jackhammers[5] = "jackhammer5.gif";
jackhammers[6] = "jackhammer6.gif";
jackhammers[7] = "jackhammer7.gif";
jackhammers[8] = "jackhammer8.gif";
jackhammers[9] = "jackhammer9.gif";
jackhammers[10] = "jackhammer10.gif";


function bounce(){

    if(curJackhammer == 10)
        curJackhammer = 0;
    else
        ++curJackhammer;
        document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src = jackhammers[curJackhammer].src;

    if(curJackhammer == 0)
        direction = "up";

    else if(curJackhammer == 10)
        direction = "down";
        document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src = jackhammers[curJackhammer];
}

function startBouncing(){

    if (begin)
        clearInterval (begin);
    begin = setInterval("bounce()",90);
}


/* ]]> */

</script>

</head>

<body>

<h1>Jackhammer Man</h1>

<p><img src="jackhammer1.gif" height="113" width="100" alt="Image of a man with a jackhammer." /></p>

<form action="" enctype="text/plain">
    <p>
        <input type="button" value="Start Bouncing" onclick="startBouncing();" />
        <input type="button" value="Stop Bouncing" onclick="clearInterval(begin);" />
    </p>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Looks like there are curly brackets -- { and } -- missing after your `else` and `else if`

Answer (score 0):

It starts with jackhammer1 because in the html source you have `<img src="jackhammer1.gif"...` instead of jackhammer0, and *also* when the user clicks the button to start bouncing, it will start with jackhammer1 because in the javascript you increment `curJackhammer` from 0 to 1 *before* you swap the images.

I think the following code will do what you want... (not sure what you were trying to do with the `direction = "up" / "down"`, though).

And note that curly brackets are usually needed after `if` and `else` in javascript, though they are optional if only a single command follows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>    
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>JackHammer</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var curJackhammer = 0;
var begin;

function bounce() {
    document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = 
         'jackhammer' + curJackhammer + '.gif';
    curJackhammer ++;
    if (curJackhammer > 10) {
        curJackhammer = 0;
    }
}

function startBouncing(){
    if (begin) {
        clearInterval (begin);
    }
    begin = setInterval(bounce,90);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Jackhammer Man</h1>

<p><img src="jackhammer1.gif" height="113" width="100" 
alt="Image of a man with a jackhammer." /></p>

<form action="" enctype="text/plain">
    <p>
        <input type="button" value="Start Bouncing" onclick="startBouncing();" />
        <input type="button" value="Stop Bouncing" onclick="clearInterval(begin);" />
    </p>
</form>

</body>

</html>​
```